# Any way to use a scan as a signature in Preview (Yosemite)?

Tags: pdf, preview

I want to add my signature to PDFs in Preview, but the Trackpad/Camera method is terrible.

Any way to add a scanned signature to Preview??

Comment: And you do not want to use Adobe Reader (a free app)

Comment: @Ruskes How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera capture method works just fine, so long as you get the basics right.

- Write your signature in black on a sheet of clean white paper.
- Take your MacBook, camera etc over to the window, facing inwards.
- Hold paper, now in daylight, to camera.
- Done.

If the lighting is bad, the result will be bad.

Answer (score 1):

sadly the only ways to add a signature in Preview, is by using the two different ways you mentioned. You could type your name in pages, print it out and use the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those who don't have a trackpad, and who also think the camera "scanned" signature looks crappy:
Open up a random PDF in the Mail app on your iPhone or iPad, press the mark up icon on the top left, then the + icon on the bottom right, then signature. Create your signature here. It is then synced to all of your devices for use.